# Where is this bridge, what is this city?

Tags: europe, locate-this

I am trying to locate that old bridge.  Do you recognize the bridge or the city?

[image]

It is a snapshot from a TV documentary, the commentary mentionned Nice or Nizza but these cities don't seem to have such large rivers.  I searched the Internet and they don't really look like that.

I tried a reverse image search, but all I got is south european landscapes.  And the picture doesn't have any useful EXIF metadata as I did the screenshot myself.

I am sure some of you will recognize this place immediately.

Comment: Just a side note re “…Nice or Nizza but these cities don't seem to have such large rivers”: Nice and Nizza are the French and Italian names for the same city, not two different cities.

Comment: I wasn't sure.  I found a Nizza Monferrato in Italy but it is really small.

Comment: @PLL And also _Nissa_ in the [local dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ni%C3%A7ard_dialect). Florian, yep Nizza Monferrato is in my region and has nothing to do with the Nizza on the French riviera.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Its the Triana Bridge in Seville (https://goo.gl/maps/hzvkLAHhsFkoeESPA). Google Images link: https://www.google.com/search?q=triana+bridge+seville+spain Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puente_de_Isabel_II

Comment: Another point of interest in the photo is the Plaza de Toros, the local bullfighting arena - it's the large round building with all the interior arches just below the right end of the bridge.

Answer (score 27):

A Google image search brings up [this reference](https://footage.framepool.com/en/shot/913672310-seville-city-density-lifestyle-daily-life-city-centre).

The bridge is the *Puente de Isabel II* in Seville, Spain.

Comment: Thanks.  I can only accept one answer but I upvoted both.  I tried the google image search, but I didn't find it.  Or maybe I didn't look carefully.

Comment: Indeed, I looked at the "visually similar images" in the search results, not the links below.  I'll know for next time.

Comment: @FlorianF That's one of the qurks of Google. When I searched using the image you posted the reference I posted was the first result!

Answer (score 15):

I can't believe I recognised it from our trip to Spain last year.

I'm fairly certain that's actually the view of the Triana from the top of the [Giralda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giralda) - the bell tower of Seville Cathedral.

Comment: It's a similar view angle, but the camera is further back than La Giralda - you can see the southwest corner of the cathedral itself at the right side of the photo, which isn't visible from the bell tower. Another answer links the original source video for this photo, which was taken from a helicopter. You're spot-on with what we're looking at, though.

Comment: Thanks, I did wonder about that corner which I noticed but I don't have any shots that showed it.